# Lambda Nodejs - (node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<Object>

Tags: node.js, lambda

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {      
      try {

        const { headers, body } = event;

        //This is where I forgot the "await" keyword

        const input = ValidateInput(body); //Returns Promise

        callback(null, true);

      }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        callback(null, false);
      }
}
```

When calling a function that returns a promise and forgetting to create an await expression promise function call, and that function rejects the promise, Lambda logs this error in cloudwatch

```
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<Object>
```

The fix is simple, don't forget the await expression

```
const input = await ValidateInput(body); //Return Promise
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix is simple, don't forget the await expression

```
const input = await ValidateInput(body); //Return Promise
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the solution is to ensure you await the promise:

```
const input = await ValidateInput(body);
```

But I thought I'd add a little context around why this occurs.

Since Promises can be stored in variables and chained at any point, there's no way for the library to know whether or not a Promise chain will have a .catch associated with it some time in the future. Many libraries therefore have a default behaviour of writing to the console if the rejected Promise has not been handled within a number of passes of the event loop; which is why you see this in the log.

You should generally take this warning as implying that you haven't awaited something you should have. As in reality, it's rare that you'd see it on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS doc explicitly says you don't use `callback` with an async function.

> The third argument, callback, is a function that you can call in
>   non-async functions to send a response. The callback function takes
>   two arguments: an Error and a response. The response object must be
>   compatible with JSON.stringify.
>
> For async functions, you return a response, error, or promise to the
>   runtime instead of using callback.

So, you may want to fix that in your lambda function.

See here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html#nodejs-prog-model-handler-callback